# Handling unicode characters that aren't displayed correctly in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the SQL query:

```
DECLARE @objname nvarchar(255)
set @objname='漢字'
select @objname
```

When I run this query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I get the following:

```
??
```

The question:is there anything I should change in my SQL query to get 漢字 in the result, or it is a matter of codepages, etc?

Comment: Append `N` i.e. `set @objname=N'漢字'`. `N` stands for National language character set that you have a `NVARCHAR`.

Comment: You don't have [hieroglyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Egyptian_hieroglyphs), you have [Chinese characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_characters).

Comment: @YogeshSharma, thank you!

Comment: Prefix Unicode character string constants with the letter N. Without the N prefix, the string is converted to the default code page of the database. This default code page may not recognize certain characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NVarchar` variable are denoted by `N'<Value>` so it would be

```
DECLARE @objname nvarchar(255)
set @objname=N'漢字'
select @objname
```

Now the output will be `漢字` as it has been set. Run above code.

Answer (score 7):

You should use this:

```
DECLARE @objname nvarchar(255)
set @objname = N'漢字'
select @objname
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding some context around the other answers:

You need to declare your string assignment using the `N` prefix (the N stands for "National Character") as you need to explicitly say you are passing a string containing unicode characters here (or an nchar, ntext etc if you were using those).

[Microsoft's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) description is

> Prefix a Unicode character string constants with the letter N to
>   signal UCS-2 or UTF-16 input, depending on whether an SC collation is
>   used or not. Without the N prefix, the string is converted to the
>   default code page of the database that may not recognize certain
>   characters. Starting with SQL Server 2019 preview, when a UTF-8
>   enabled collation is used, the default code page is capable of storing
>   UNICODE UTF-8 character set.

So your assignment will as per other answers be `set @objname = N'漢字'`

You should also be aware to use the prefix in other instances, such as where clauses when filtering on `nvarchar` columns, otherwise you can encounter issues such as performance degradation from implicit conversions.